# Extract DOM property value using Selenium

Tags: java, dom, selenium-webdriver

In Firebug and other DevTools you can get the DOM properties and values corresponding to an HTML element.

How can such values be extracted using selenium-java code?
I had tried `getAttribute()`, but it seems to be working only for HTML attributes and not for DOM properties like "value" or "spellcheck" etc.

The reason I went for this approach is that the value associated with the `<input>` text field (snippet below) is run-time generated and data is bound to it using Knockout. And hence it's not possible to capture them with standard approaches like `getText()`, `getAttribute("value")`, `getAttribute("text")`, `getAttribute("innerHTML")`,  `getAttribute("innertext")`, etc.

HTML snippet for the HTML element:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" style="cursor: text" readonly="readonly" data-bind="textInput: url">
```

[image: Firebug's DOM panel displaying DOM properties of an <input> element]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but it might give someone else a hand out

Use this in the console

```
$$("input.form-control").value
```

if it returns the required you will have to execute the `Javascript` using `WebDriver` i.e.

```
driver.ExecuteScript("var data = arguments[0].value; return data;", (Element as RemoteWebElement)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Selenium documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-), there is only the `getAttribute()` function, which is described as follows:

> Get the value of a the given attribute of the element. Will return the current value, even if this has been modified after the page has been loaded. More exactly, this method will return the value of the given attribute, unless that attribute is not present, in which case the value of the property with the same name is returned (for example for the "value" property of a textarea element). If neither value is set, null is returned. ...

According to this, `getAttribute("value")` should return the DOM property value in case there is no HTML attribute named `value`.

If that's not the case, it may be a timing issue. I.e. the value is read by Selenium before it gets set.

Comment: tried in debug mode in eclipse, so that i can be sure its not a page sync issue. I had waited for the page to load. getAttribute("value") returns null whereas when i check using firebug i am able to see the "value" correctly. Does knockout js data-binding has got to do anything with this?

Comment: I don't think so, as the `value` property obviously gets set properly according to your screenshot. So, Selenium should be able to read it. Though I didn't use Knockout.js yet to tell that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 4 use getDomAttribute() and getDomProperty().